# MySQL: Return true if all values are in present

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can i check if all days are filled in my db using one query, i have array containing all days that should be filled and my db. I was thinking of use `IN` but cant get it to work, my query looks like this so far

```
SELECT `User` . * , `Department`.`name`, if(Hour.date IN('2014-05-05', '2014-05-05', ...), 1, 0) AS all_days_filled
FROM `kadry`.`users` AS `User`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `kadry`.`departments` AS `Department` ON ( `Department`.`id` = `User`.`assigned` )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `kadry`.`hours` AS `Hour` ON ( `Hour`.`subordinate_id` = `User`.`id` )
WHERE `User`.`assigned`
IN (
    '001004012', '116', '113', '114', '004001002'
)
AND `role` != 'superior'
AND `Department`.`active` = '1'
AND `User`.`active` = '1'
AND ((date( discharge ) > '2014-05-01')
OR (
    discharge IS NULL
   )
)
GROUP BY `User`.`id`
ORDER BY `Department`.`name` ASC , `User`.`l_name` ASC
```

Comment: You can try like `case when Hour.date IN('2014-05-05', '2014-05-05', ...) then 1 else 0 end AS all_days_filled`

Comment: @Rahul that's exactly the same thing as what the OP already has.

Comment: What do you mean by "all days filled"? Does that mean all days in a particular range are present in the data?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, GROUP BY is (IMO) best avoided.

Comment: @siride Yes, query should return `1` if all days are present in joined  `Hour` table

Comment: @Strawberry: this is why I really wish MySQL did not allow non-aggregate, non-group columns in the SELECT list with a GROUP BY by default. It just leads to bad code and bad results.

Comment: @siride I almost agree with you, except that (rather frustratingly) GROUP BY does seem to be fractionally faster than DISTINCT on larger data sets.

Comment: @Strawberry: but in that case, you'd still have all of the group columns in the select list and no other columns. There's never a situation where including non-grouped, non-aggregate columns in the select list makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query solves my problem

```
SELECT `User`. * , `Department`.`name` , IF( SUM( IF( Hour.date
IN (
    "2014-05-05", "2014-05-06", "2014-05-07", "2014-05-08", "2014-05-09", "2014-05-12", "2014-05-13", "2014-05-14", "2014-05-15", "2014-05-16", "2014-05-19", "2014-05-20", "2014-05-21", "2014-05-22", "2014-05-23", "2014-05-26", "2014-05-27", "2014-05-28", "2014-05-29", "2014-05-30"
), 1, 0 ) ) >=20, 1, 0 ) AS all_filled
FROM `kadry`.`users` AS `User`
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `kadry`.`departments` AS `Department` ON ( `Department`.`id` = `User`.`assigned` )
     LEFT OUTER JOIN `kadry`.`hours` AS `Hour` ON ( `Hour`.`subordinate_id` = `User`.`id`
AND date( `Hour`.`date` )
BETWEEN '2014-05-01'
AND '2014-05-31' )
    WHERE `User`.`assigned`
    IN (
        '001004012', '116', '113', '114', '004001002'
        )
    AND `role` != 'superior'
    AND `Department`.`active` = '1'
    AND `User`.`active` = '1'
    AND (
        (
            date( discharge ) > '2014-05-01'
        )
    OR (
    discharge IS NULL
    )
)
GROUP BY `User`.`id`
ORDER BY `Department`.`name` ASC , `User`.`l_name` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `GROUP_CONCAT` function. It'll return the dates joined by a comma by default. If you need a different separator, you can specify it as an option. You can also put `DISTINCT` and `ORDER BY` inside your `GROUP_CONCAT`.

See the mysql doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT `User` . * , `Department`.`name`, 
CASE
WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(Hour.date ORDER BY HOUR.date) = '2014-05-01, 2014-05-02, ...' THEN 1 
ELSE 0
END AS all_days_filled
FROM `kadry`.`users` AS `User`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `kadry`.`departments` AS `Department` ON ( `Department`.`id` = `User`.`assigned` )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `kadry`.`hours` AS `Hour` ON ( `Hour`.`subordinate_id` = `User`.`id` )
WHERE `User`.`assigned`
IN (
    '001004012', '116', '113', '114', '004001002'
)
AND `role` != 'superior'
AND `Department`.`active` = '1'
AND `User`.`active` = '1'
AND ((date( discharge ) > '2014-05-01')
OR (
    discharge IS NULL
   )
)
GROUP BY `User`.`id`
ORDER BY `Department`.`name` ASC , `User`.`l_name` ASC
```

Comment: Depending on how many dates there are, this could overflow the GROUP_CONCAT length.

Comment: There will never be more than 24 dates

Comment: with 24 dates, you won't have to worry about overflow errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUM` to add up the number of days in the given range. Compare the sum with the actual number of days in the range. If they aren't equal, you are missing days. Here's the relevant code:

```
IF(SUM(IF(Hour.date BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31', 1, 0)) = 31, 1, 0) AS all_filled
```

Comment: This is almost perfect, but can i exclude dates like `2014-05-03` which is saturday?

Comment: @Viszman: yes. Just add some additional logic, for example: `IF(Hour.date BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31' AND Hour.date <> '2014-05-03', 1, 0)`. You might want to have a table of dates that will tell you what is and isn't a weekend/holiday, and then join against that so that you can include that logic in your `IF()` expression, rather than hard-coding dates.

Comment: i wrote little function in php that gives days except tor weekends

Comment: @Viszman: how will that help with your query? I suppose you could use it to generate the list of dates when building your query.